# Is this patent applicable for gaming industry only? Can some parts of it be used in other fields of work without infringement of rights?

Tags: patent-applications, infringement

In reference to the patent: [EP2457626B1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP2457626B1)

Answer (score 1):

This a granted patent, not just an application. I see the term "game" or "game apparatus" in every independent claim so, to me, it looks like it is indeed limited to gaming only. However, you would do well to get an opinion from a patent attorney. If you want to patent its application in other contexts, it is prior art and may impact patentability.